# How Can I Handle Push Notification When App Is Not Running?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, onesignal

I added onesignal to my project for send any news notification to show them a detail view when they clicked to the notification. It is working well when the app is foreground or background but it is not working when the app is not running.

I researched it and they said didRecieve method is not calling when app was not started. So, I must handle notification at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, I tried it but same.

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import OneSignal
import GoogleMobileAds
import UserNotifications
import SDWebImageWebPCoder

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var shortcutItemToProcess: UIApplicationShortcutItem?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)

        let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false]
        OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
        appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        handleNotificationAction: nil,
        settings: onesignalInitSettings)
        OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification
        OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
        })

        let WebPCoder = SDImageWebPCoder.shared
        SDImageCodersManager.shared.addCoder(WebPCoder)

        registerForPushNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func registerForPushNotifications() {

        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.delegate = self

        let readAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "read", title: "Read", options: [.foreground])
        let closeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "close", title: "Close", options: [])

        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "etkilesim", actions: [readAction, closeAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

        notificationCenter.setNotificationCategories([category])

        notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            guard granted else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.

        // Grab a reference to the shortcutItem to use in the scene
        if let shortcutItem = options.shortcutItem {
            shortcutItemToProcess = shortcutItem
        }

        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        var postId:String = ""
        var postType:String = ""

        if let custom = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["custom"] as? NSDictionary{
            if let a = custom["a"] as? NSDictionary{
                if let id = a["id"] as? String{
                    postId = id
                }
                if let type = a["rights"] as? String{
                    postType = type
                }
            }
        }

        if response.actionIdentifier == "read" {
            if postId != ""{
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("Detail"), object: nil, userInfo: ["id": postId, "type": postType])
            }
        }else if response.actionIdentifier == "close" {
            print("KAPAT")
        } else {
             if postId != ""{
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("Detail"), object: nil, userInfo: ["id": postId, "type": postType])
            }
        }
        completionHandler()
    }

}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/fantageek/push-notification-in-ios-46d979e5f7ec : This article has nice explanation

Comment: Thanks @Manav, I read it but still I am researching a solution ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lol. I wrapped my code with async, it's working well now.

```
if response.actionIdentifier == "read" {
            if postId != ""{
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("Detail"), object: nil, userInfo: ["id": postId, "type": postType])
                })
                completionHandler()
            }
        }else if response.actionIdentifier == "close" {
            print("CLOSE")
            completionHandler()
        } else {
            if postId != ""{
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("Detail"), object: nil, userInfo: ["id": postId, "type": postType])
                })
                completionHandler()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add Background Modes -> Remote notifications to you app capabilities in order to fully access to delegate methods such as: `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

I would recommend you to store your remote nots on backend side linked to each user/device and make an immediate fetch of them on every app startup. This is the only way to ensure data consistency.

Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131585/save-received-remote-push-notifications-ios).

Comment: Thanks bro, but I already enabled Background Modes -> Remote notifications